# Which Tense is used here: "the loan agreement has (been) terminated"

Tags: tense, present-perfect, passive-voice

This is  from a letter I got today, and it reads:

> We hereby confirm that the loan agreement entered into between XYZ bank and aforementioned customer, **has been terminated**. We request you to remove the hypothetication of XYZ bank on the said vehicle.

Whereas, I think it should be like this:

> We hereby confirm that the loan agreement entered between XYZ bank and aforementioned customer, **has terminated**. We request you to remove the hypothetication of XYZ bank on the said vehicle.

Which tense is used here and why?

Comment: first one is correct. It has been terminated by an entity (XYZ Bank).
In the second example, you could replace has terminated with *has ended*. That would make the sentence correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When one of the parties to an agreement has exercised a right to terminate, we use the *passive construction*:

**The agreement has been terminated.**

If the agreement has reached an explicitly set term, so that it ends of its own accord, so to speak, then the passive is not used and we'd say:

**The agreement has terminated.**